# PHP string challenge

Tags: php, string, recursion

I have an string such as

```
$string = "This is my test string {ABC}. This is test {XYZ}. I am new for PHP {PHP}".
```

Now I need to replace occurrence of string within {}, in such a way that output will be:

```
This is my test string {ABC 1}. This is test {XYZ 2}. I am new for PHP {PHP 3}".
```

I am looking to resolve this with recursive function but not getting expected result.

Comment: Can you give your current recursive attempt ?

Comment: Why recursion? What is has to do with the issue?

Comment: If you were to use recursive function, you would need to specify if `{{A}B{C}}` goes as `{{A 1}B{C 2} 3}` (postorder), or as `{{A 1}B{C 3} 2}` (inorder) or as `{{A 2}B{C 3} 1}` (preorder). if such situation would not occur at all, then you really dont need recursion. Iteration would be more than enough

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{(.+?)\}/', function (array $match) use (&$i) {
    return sprintf('{%s %d}', $match[1], $i++);
}, $string);
```

The "trick" is to simply keep an external counter running, here `$i`, which is used in the anonymous callback via `use (&$i)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursion here. Simply counting.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/\{([^}]*+)\}/",function($m) {
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    return "{".$m[1]." ".$count."}";
},$string);
```

Comment: Note that the problem with `static` is that the count will stay constant even across several invocations of this code. I.e., if you're doing this in a loop, the next strings will come back with `{ABC 4} {XYZ 5}` etc.

Comment: @deceze Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. Although, we don't know, but this might be desired behaviour XD

Answer (score 0):

If you really need recursive :^ )

```
$string = "This is my test string {ABC}. This is test {XYZ}. I am new for PHP {PHP}";

function my_replace($string, $count = 1)
    {
    if ($string)
        {
        return preg_replace_callback('/\{(.+?)\}(.*)$/', function (array $match) use ($count)
            {
            return sprintf('{%s %d} %s', $match[1], $count, my_replace($match[2], $count + 1));
            }, $string, 1);
        }
    }
echo my_replace($string);
```

Comment: Uuhh, nice. I think...?

Comment: But your braces are madness. ;-P

Comment: @deceze, just some modifications of your answer.